# Java Fatjar throwing error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, gradle, java-8, build.gradle

I have created a java library with some factory and service class. Its a simple java 8 and gradle 7.6.3 project. My use case is to create a fatjar which can be used by anyone. fatjar is getting built with my custom class files and dependencies that i have added in build.gradle. But on trying to access the class in a client code i am getting NoClassDefFoundError

build.gradle in jar project -

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}
version = "1.0.0"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    
}
jacoco{
toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
    afterEvaluate {
       classDirectories.from = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
           fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['**/com/test/lib/interfaces/**'])
       })
   }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:secretsmanager:2.21.44'
       implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.21.44'
       implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
        implementation'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.0'
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog:1.3.6'


        implementation'com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:4.7.3'
    implementation  'com.azure:azure-identity:1.8.3'
        implementation'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-secretmanager:2.31.0'
    
    testImplementation  'junit:junit:4.13.1'
          testImplementation  'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.11.0'
          implementation group: 'com.google.auth', name: 'google-auth-library-oauth2-http', version: '1.21.0'
          
    

  
}
ext.mockitoVersion='4.11.0'


task buildJar(type: Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar ',  
            'Implementation-Version': version       
    }
    baseName = "testlibrary"
        from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Created jar using ./gradlew clean buildJar command
Please note i dont have any main method. Its just a normal library whos factory method will be used to create a cloud provider and then some related cloud operations will be performed.

CLient Code - Created a folder name libs and placed the jar inside it.
added dependency -

```
implementation files('libs/testlibrary.jar')
```

Did a gradle refres from the IDE. I could see the jar under project and external dependencies and it had my custom java filea and dependent files specified in build.gradle.

Note: If i do a normal ./gradlew clean build, jar is getting created with only my custom files .but no gradle dependecies and client code is able to find my TestFactory class.it fails when it goes inside as it cant find dependencies like say logger.But with above task, it creates jar with gradle defined dependencies,but it cant find my file itself.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/lib/factory/TestFactory
    at tes.Library.main(Library.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.lib.factory.TestFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The method `from` accepts an object representing files as its first argument, not a `Closure` (see [CopySpec documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html)).

So to fix you should remove the outer set of braces and write instead:

```
from configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
```

Comment: Still getting the same error.  ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/lib/factory/TestFactory
 at tes.Library.main(Library.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.lib.factory.TestFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)```

Comment: Hmmm I don't know. Your setup works fine on my machine